# How to OFFSET a closed workbook alternative with Vlookup or Index & small

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, vlookup, offset

I have two workbooks, one where I am doing the Vlookup and the other contains the table I need to retrieve the information from.

I am trying to basically Vlookup the table found in the other workbook '[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'! below row 3 as sometimes the lookup retrieves information from the second row and I don't want those parameters from the table. The reason I can't start the Vlookup at the third row of the table is because my lookup table can have data entered into it (shifting the rows down) and this shifts the absolute references of the table array within my Vlookup formula (see example below):

For example if I enter, `=VLOOKUP("TEST 1_SL.1V.L",'[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'!$A$3:$FZ$10000,ROWS($A$1:$A6),FALSE)` and a new entry/row is added (So another Test 1_SL.1V.L in column A for example) to the workbook that has the lookup table '[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes' then my formula becomes `=VLOOKUP("TEST 1_SL.1V.L",OFFSET(('[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'!$A$4:$FZ$10000),2,0),ROWS($A$1:$A6),FALSE).` **Notice how $A$3 --> $A$4**

To handle this I am attempting to do a Vlookup from row 1 and offsetting it by 2 rows down, because the absolute references ($A$1 below) don't seem to change when a new row is added to the workbook whenever the absoulate references are inside an OFFSET function (So the $A$1 doesn't change to $A$2 when a new data entry is added (a new row) to [Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'). Now this formula below only works when I have the other workbook open where the lookup table is coming from, that is [Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'! , **if I close it then my Vlookup formula is returning a #VALUE error because the workbook I am referencing is closed so the OFFSET produces a #VALUE error**

**My Question:** Are there any adjustments or suggestions to my code that I can make to replace my OFFSET function not working whenever I close the other workbook or perhaps a different approach?

Here is the formula I am using:

`=VLOOKUP('Operation base Q'!$H$5,OFFSET(('[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'!$A$1:$FZ$1000),2,0),ROWS($A$1:$A6),FALSE)`

**Here is a screenshot of the lookup data from the file path '[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes' :**

[image]

**Another ALTERNATIVE solution** I am trying to use is an Index formula with a Small Array (Hold Ctrl+Shift+Enter whenever entering an array). The array makes my sheet very slow and it won't grab the "first" lookup value (as in the Third row and below) IF the second row isn't filled in with the lookup value (see screenshot below of the workbook '[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'! where the second row is different as I am looking up TEST 1, so my formula is returning the fourth row when I want it to return the third row).

[image]

Here is the formula I am using for this alternative:

`=INDEX(INDEX('[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'!$A$2:$FZ$10001,0,ROWS($1:6)),SMALL(IF('Operation base Q'!$H$5='[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'!$A:$A,ROW('[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'!$A:$A),""),1))*`

**A third solution** I tried using is a Double INDEX & MATCH combination, but whenever I add a new line to the other workbook, the absolute reference changes as well, here is what I mean:

This is the formula I am trying to use (third alternative):

`=INDEX(INDEX('[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'!**$A$3:$FZ$10000**,0,ROWS($1:6)),MATCH('Operation base Q'!$H$5,'[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'!**$A$3:$A$1000**,0))`

But whenever I insert a new row into the Database_IRR 200-2s workbook, the absolute references change like this (see in bold):

`=INDEX(INDEX('[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'!**$A$4:$FZ$10001**,0,ROWS($1:6)),MATCH('Operation base Q'!$H$5,'[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'!**$A$4:$A$1001**,0))`

Cross-referencing another post I made on: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vlookup-offset-value-error.1139372/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `SUMPRODUCT` with `OFFSET` inside `VLOOKUP` function, try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'!$A$3:$A$1000='Operation base Q'!$H$5)*'[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'!$A$3:$FZ$10000)
```

Comment: I have replaced the ```Offset``` portion of ```=VLOOKUP('Operation base Q'!$H$5,OFFSET(('[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'!$A$1:$FZ$1000),2,0),ROWS($A$1:$A6),FALSE)``` with your ```SUMPRODUCT``` suggestion and it doesn't seem to be quite working, this is what I have could you please correct me: ```=VLOOKUP('Operation base Q'!$H$5,SUMPRODUCT(('[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'!$A$3:$A$1000='Operation base Q'!$H$5)*'[Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm]Changes'!$A$3:$FZ$10000),ROWS($A$1:$A6),FALSE)```

Comment: you can replace VLOOKUP with SUMPRODUCT as follows SUMPRODUCT = (range1 = criteria1 * range2 = criteria2 * table array)